# Rasdial falsely reports successful connection

Tags: networking, ras

Windows Server 2012 R2, uses RASDIAL as part of an automation routine to connect to a VPN.  This has been working for a year or more, and recently started failing, though in a very unexpected way.

If I run the rasdial command, it reports that the connection to the VPN was successful, however no connection was made and running again to get a list of connections shows none.  Even more interesting than this false positive is that it doesn't matter what I use for a username/pass, it still reports success.

```
C:\MyDir>rasdial "This Connection" username password
Successfully connected to This Connection
Command completed successfully.

C:\MyDir>rasdial
No connections
Command completed successfully.
```

I can change passwords so I know it shouldn't work and the result is identical.  Even worse, this returns an exit code of 0, which my automation program accepts as success.

I'm about to give the server a reboot and start digging into this more, but why in the world would rasdial return that kind of success when it obviously failed?